# Tab bar and Mapview issues

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, mkmapview

I'm really confused about this issue. I have recently been having issues with my mapview tab in my application. Even to the point of starting over again. I'm just wondering if I am the only one having this issue or am I doing something wrong here.

I am fairly new to iOS but I know how to define a mapview's center and span in order to center on the user's location.

I've built this in its own view and it seems to work but when I put it in a tab controller...I have an issue. The map stays zoomed out while showing the user's location.  It's supposed to show the user's location zoomed in.

My MapViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.mapView.delegate self];
    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [userLocation coordinate];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc, 500, 500);
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

I also thought it could have something to do with the way I created the tab controller in the delegate.

My app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[NWSWelcomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NWSWelcomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[NWSMapViewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NWSMapViewViewController" bundle:nil];
  //  UIViewController *viewController3 = [[NWSSettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NWSSettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2, /* viewController3 */];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

I am writing for iOS 5.1 and I am using the latest Xcode.

Yes, I have the settings for zooming enabled on the mapView.

I just want to get the user location to zoom in the mapview to the user's location.

Comment: I'm thinking about it more and I'm wondering if I need to add something when the tab is pressed? Because I notice that the view flickers when I switch to the tab with the map. As if it were resetting itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self.mapView.delegate self];
```

does nothing (it is trying to send the message `self` to `self.mapView.delegate`).

It doesn't actually set the map view's `delegate` and so the `didUpdateUserLocation` never gets called.

What you probably meant was:

```
[self.mapView setDelegate:self];
```

or this:

```
self.mapView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Yup... that was the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This type of problems can be solved by storyboard also.
Go to the storyboard->controller->mapView
right click on the mapView a popover will show having a point delegate drag the delegate + point to controller[image: right click on map view![][1]]