# Why is [object.delegate self] allowed in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, selector, self

I have seen several examples of Objective-C code, where a delegate needs to be defined. For example, when using MapKit, I see statements such as:

```
[self.mapView.delegate self];
```

I also sometimes see the following:

```
[self.mapView setDelegate:self];
```

And still I find some examples that do the following:

```
self.mapView.delegate = self;
```

I understand how the second and third are equivalent, however I do not understand how the first is able to run, let alone compile.  What I mean is: how is `self` a valid selector in this context?  How does this code translate to an assignment statement for the delegate property?

Comment: Can you show #1 in the context of the call it's being used in?  It's not clear to me either how that works.

Comment: Maybe self is a method..? (Just a random guess, but I don't think the compiler let's you name a method called `self` anyway)

Comment: @TheAmateurProgrammer `self` is a reserved word, so no, that's not allowed, no more than having a method called `while`, `default` or `break`.

Comment: @trojanfoe I just tested it.  I'm allowed to have a method called `self`, but the compiler requires you to return it's own class.  So say a class called `TestClass` can technically implement a method called `-(TestClass*)self;` and return something else, but it seems pretty meaningless to me.

Comment: #1 doesn't actually work. It just sends a `self` message to the delegate. See this answer as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145975/tab-bar-and-mapview-issues

Comment: @TheAmateurProgrammer That's interesting and something I didn't know.

Comment: @trojanfoe I was curious, and apparently you can even have a method called `while`. (Although self isn't actually a reserved word, just an implicit argument to all Objective-C methods)

Comment: @cobbal Curiouser and curiouser.  I don't see how that works (my statements about reserved words come from my experience with C and C++; obviously this doesn't transfer into Objective-C!).

Comment: Having a method named `self` or `while` is no different than having a string `"self"` or `"while"`. You are simply sending a message to the object, which is a string of characters. There are no reserved method names, you can use any method name you want.

Answer (score 11):

`self` in `[self.mapView.delegate self];` and `[self.mapView setDelegate:self];` are different — yet related things. while the latter self represents the object in its scope it is used, `[object self]` is a method `-(id)self` defined in the NSObject protocol.

[from the doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCGEBBJ):

> **self**
>   Returns the receiver. (required)
>
> ```
> - (id)self
> ```
>
> Return Value The receiver.
>
> Availability Available in OS X v10.0 and later.

As the NSObject class implements the NSObject protocol, nearly any object we use in our codes will understand this method.

A clue, what it useful for, gives us the [GNUStep documentation](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Base/Reference/NSObject.html#method%24%28NSObject%29-self):

> self
>
> ```
> - (id) self;
> ```
>
> Availability: OpenStep
>
> Returns the receiver. In a proxy, this may (but is not required to) return the proxied object.

We can use it for proxies.
Also in KVC it can be useful that there is a method called `self`, as the operator needs a right key path, but actually the object itself is what we need:

```
NSArray *numbers = @[@1, @1, @2 ,@3, @5]
NSNumber* sum = [numbers valueForKeyPath: @"@sum.self"];
```

`sum` will be `12`.

---

`[self.mapView setDelegate:self];` and `self.mapView.delegate = self;` are equivalent and `self` sends for the object it is used in. Basically each Objective-C message translates to a C function, that takes at least two parameters. `-setDelegate:` would be translation in runtime to

```
void setDelegate(id self, SEL _cmd, id delegate)
{
    // implementation ....
}
```

As you can see here, `self` is just the default name of the object passed in as the first parameter by the runtime and refers to the object of the class the method is defined on.

Although it is often referred as a keyword, `self` isn't. it is just a convention. As it is possible to construct Objective-C methods by using C functions, the Implementation IMP type and selector SEL type, you could decide to call the first object differently, like `this` if you would like to have C++ naming.